# Remove unwanted data entries

Tags: r, filter

Apologise for the rubbish title but struggling to phrase the problem.

I receive data from a client, they manually start and stop tests on site but some times they double press start test or stop test and this makes it hard for me to automate the output.

Here is some data

```
dput(test)
structure(list(time = structure(c(1645290963, 1645291107, 1645291112, 
1645291203, 1645291306, 1645291441, 1645291532, 1645291689, 1645291721, 
1645291866, 1645292051, 1645292182, 1645292444, 1645292539, 1645292557, 
1645292935, 1645293077, 1645293117, 1645293229, 1645293275, 1645293425, 
1645293429, 1645293555, 1645293584, 1645293735), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), type = c("StartTesting", "StopTesting", "StartTesting", 
"StopTesting", "StartTesting", "StopTesting", "StartTesting", 
"StopTesting", "StartTesting", "StopTesting", "StartTesting", 
"StopTesting", "StartTesting", "StopTesting", "StopTesting", 
"StartTesting", "StopTesting", "StartTesting", "StopTesting", 
"StartTesting", "StopTesting", "StartTesting", "StopTesting", 
"StartTesting", "StopTesting"), comments = c("", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "")), row.names = c("event.12", "event.13", "event.14", 
"event.15", "event.16", "event.17", "event.18", "event.19", "event.20", 
"event.21", "event.22", "event.23", "event.25", "event.26", "event.27", 
"event.28", "event.29", "event.30", "event.31", "event.32", "event.33", 
"event.34", "event.35", "event.36", "event.37"), class = "data.frame")
```

Difficult to spot but at rowname - event.26 they pressed  `StopTesting` twice.  I need to find a way to ensure there are equal amounts of starts and stops as part of my data processing I am try to clean data as shown below, but it stops me `cbind` the data back together.

```
testdatstart <- filter(test, type =="StartTesting")
names(testdatstart)[names(testdatstart) == 'time'] <- 'TestStart'
names(testdatstart)[names(testdatstart) == 'comments'] <- 'StartComments'

testdatfin <- filter(test, type =="StopTesting")
names(testdatfin)[names(testdatfin) == 'time'] <- 'TestStop'
names(testdatfin)[names(testdatfin) == 'comments'] <- 'StopComments'

testdat <- cbind(testdatstart, testdatfin)
testdat <- testdat %>%
  select(TestStart,TestStop, StartComments, StopComments)
```

and my desired output is this (I manually removed event.26 to achieve this)

```
dput(testdat)
structure(list(TestStart = structure(c(1645290963, 1645291112, 
1645291306, 1645291532, 1645291721, 1645292051, 1645292444, 1645292935, 
1645293117, 1645293275, 1645293429, 1645293584), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), TestStop = structure(c(1645291107, 1645291203, 1645291441, 
1645291689, 1645291866, 1645292182, 1645292539, 1645293077, 1645293229, 
1645293425, 1645293555, 1645293735), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), StartComments = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", ""), StopComments = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("event.12", 
"event.14", "event.16", "event.18", "event.20", "event.22", "event.25", 
"event.28", "event.30", "event.32", "event.34", "event.36"))
```

So I am struggling to find a way to identify the pattern required, which should run start,stop,start,stop etc and then delete the second off the double entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(id = cumsum(type == "StartTesting")) %>% 
  arrange(id, type, desc(time)) %>% 
  distinct(id, type, .keep_all = T) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = c(time, comments))  

      id time_StartTesting   time_StopTesting    comments_StartTesting comments_StopTesting
   <int> <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr>                 <chr>               
 1     1 2022-02-19 18:16:03 2022-02-19 18:18:27 ""                    ""                  
 2     2 2022-02-19 18:18:32 2022-02-19 18:20:03 ""                    ""                  
 3     3 2022-02-19 18:21:46 2022-02-19 18:24:01 ""                    ""                  
 4     4 2022-02-19 18:25:32 2022-02-19 18:28:09 ""                    ""                  
 5     5 2022-02-19 18:28:41 2022-02-19 18:31:06 ""                    ""                  
 6     6 2022-02-19 18:34:11 2022-02-19 18:36:22 ""                    ""                  
 7     7 2022-02-19 18:40:44 2022-02-19 18:42:37 ""                    ""                  
 8     8 2022-02-19 18:48:55 2022-02-19 18:51:17 ""                    ""                  
 9     9 2022-02-19 18:51:57 2022-02-19 18:53:49 ""                    ""                  
10    10 2022-02-19 18:54:35 2022-02-19 18:57:05 ""                    ""                  
11    11 2022-02-19 18:57:09 2022-02-19 18:59:15 ""                    ""                  
12    12 2022-02-19 18:59:44 2022-02-19 19:02:15 ""                    ""
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, both of them work equally well. Could you explain how exactly the line ```mutate(id = cumsum(type == "StartTesting"))``` works?

Comment: Good to read it works for you. Consider to accept one of the answers that works for you. `type == "StartTesting"` returns TRUE (same as 1) each time type is equal to StartTesting. `Cumsum` will then add 1 each time type is equal to StartTesting, and therefore assigining the same id to consecutive rows where type is equal to StopTesting

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dplyr` package to and `filter` the type column: we simply check if `type` is equal to the previous `type` using `lag`.
Afterwards you can transform your data using `summarise`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  as_tibble(rownames = "rownames") %>% 
  filter(type != lag(type, default = "")) %>%
  group_by(gr = cumsum(type == "StartTesting")) %>%
  summarise(rownames = first(rownames), TestStart = time[1], TestStop = time[2], .groups = "drop") %>%
  select(-gr)

# A tibble: 12 x 3
   rownames TestStart           TestStop           
   <chr>    <dttm>              <dttm>             
 1 event.12 2022-02-19 18:16:03 2022-02-19 18:18:27
 2 event.14 2022-02-19 18:18:32 2022-02-19 18:20:03
 3 event.16 2022-02-19 18:21:46 2022-02-19 18:24:01
 4 event.18 2022-02-19 18:25:32 2022-02-19 18:28:09
 5 event.20 2022-02-19 18:28:41 2022-02-19 18:31:06
 6 event.22 2022-02-19 18:34:11 2022-02-19 18:36:22
 7 event.25 2022-02-19 18:40:44 2022-02-19 18:42:19
 8 event.28 2022-02-19 18:48:55 2022-02-19 18:51:17
 9 event.30 2022-02-19 18:51:57 2022-02-19 18:53:49
10 event.32 2022-02-19 18:54:35 2022-02-19 18:57:05
11 event.34 2022-02-19 18:57:09 2022-02-19 18:59:15
12 event.36 2022-02-19 18:59:44 2022-02-19 19:02:15
```